# "NOT EXISTS" in SSIS data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a data flow where I need to merge the data from two distinct sources into a target table, but also want only to insert unique values and disregard existing values.

The row key is made up of two columns, which I turned into a SHA1 hash to make it easier to merge.

The way I am doing the "NOT EXISTS" is through "left outer join" merge joins, I get the right join and later I use a conditional split to get only the null values.

Every source is sorted by the hash. The existing data source is multicast to both joins to check for existing values, I only want new ones.
[image: Heres how it looks]

The problem I'm having is that even though, to me at least, everything looks OK I am still getting unique key violations (both source1 and source2 produce entirely different keys and the keys in the data sets are unique) and I can't trace the issue.

I tried slowing everything down by adding more sorts and even after the "existing data" source finishes it still produces unique key violations.

Comment: the boring reality is that you will probably get better performance if you use a dataflow to completely import your source data into a staging table, and then do all this cleansing with a stored proc that updates your target table.

Comment: bawww, booooo. Yeah, I'm leaning towards that. Soon enough I'll have more staging tables than non-staging tables, already have plenty

Answer (score 4):

If you want to perform NOT Exists operation, LOOKUP component in full cache with "Redirect no match output" configured is the one you should use. Performance are pretty good with it.

This exemple could help : http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/46-SSIS-Upsert-With-Lookup-Transform.html

Hope this help,