# How to get unmatched data between two sources in SSIS Data Flow?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2008

I have two data sources, one sql table, one flat file (csv). Both sources have exact same columns. Example Data:

Table:

```
HCN  Name  Surname   DOB
111  John   Black    2013-12-10
222  Jack   White    1989-01-14
333  Brian  Brown    2000-04-22
```

FlatFile:

```
HCN  Name  Surname   DOB
111  John   Black    2013-12-10
444  Alex   Smith    1978-05-16
```

Note that the column HCN is the primary key. What I need to do is to get such records included by the table but FlatFile.

Expected output:

```
HCN  Name  Surname   DOB
222  Jack   White    1989-01-14
333  Brian  Brown    2000-04-22
```

I have to do it in Data Flow of my SSIS Package. I am doing below to get the matching records (HCN:111), but how I can get the unmatched ones I could not figure out. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Use a Lookup instead of a Merge Join, then use the Not Matched output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253755/not-exists-in-ssis-data-flow

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["NOT EXISTS" in SSIS data flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253755/not-exists-in-ssis-data-flow)

Comment: Receiving error: "The destination component does not have any available inputs for use in creating a path" when I try to connect both source files to a lookup ?? @EzLo

Comment: you don't have to connect the reference table to the lookup, you set it up in the lookup connections directly (it only has 1 input as flow).

Comment: I don't think you can do a Lookup from a Flat File Connection, can you?

Comment: Load the contents to a cache manager in a previous data flow, then you can use the lookup against the cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1 : LOOKUP:**
You can follows theses steps:

- add a lookup transformation
  in connection tab, choose your flatfile connexion
  in column tab, drag and drop the Join column
  in general tab, handle not matching entries by redirect rows
- Redirect the non matching output to your destination

[image]

**SOLUTION 2 : LEFT ANTI JOIN**

You can follows theses steps:

**1** Sort datasets / or modifiy the properties of the source to isSorted
   = true

**2** Use a LEFT JOIN on the key, and add a new column containing the id of the right side

**3** Add a conditional split condition on right
   side ID is null

Then redirect CASE 1 splited data to your destination, you have only rows from the left side without right side correspondance

[image]

Comment: I justs add an alternative solution LOOKUP as suggested by comments

Comment: You cannot use a Flat File in a Lookup. Are you suggesting to put the flat file into a "cache" connection, and THEN using it in a Lookup?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I suggest you to load Flat file data into OLEDB staging table, Which is optional. If you Load flat file data into destination, you can align primary keys for the look up.

Create a staging table to insert unmatched records, you will only need asynchronous transformation in this case

Refer Below for Look up Transformation 
[image]

Check for Look up Columns:

Here is example

[image]