# How can I get all matching rows from lookup using full cache mode?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I need to make a lookup between two tables T1(A,B,C) and T2(A,B,C,D,E) on column C to get all column B values that are matching :

T1 :

[image]

T2 :

[image]

When I choose Full cache Mode I get only the first matching row (I'm only interested by column B values): 12122 but I need to get also 12123 and 12124 because C matches also with these rows.

I've tried to use Partial and no cache modes by using custom query with `inner join` (which returns all needed rows when executing the query in SSMS) but doesn't return all rows and it's killing performence.

I've tried also the solution proposed here :

[How to get unmatched data between two sources in SSIS Data Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681600/how-to-get-unmatched-data-between-two-sources-in-ssis-data-flow)

And it gives the same results as lookup plus, I need to redirect unmatched rows to new table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the cache mode will affect your result, and it is performance based. The ultimate explanation is:

> •If there are multiple matches in the reference table, the Lookup
>   transformation returns only the first match returned by the lookup
>   query. If multiple matches are found, the Lookup transformation
>   generates an error or warning only when the transformation has been
>   configured to load all the reference dataset into the cache. In this
>   case, the Lookup transformation generates a warning when the
>   transformation detects multiple matches as the transformation fills
>   the cache.

To get the matched `B` from T2, you can just use the SQL in OLD DB source(command), for example:

```
SELECT distinct T2.B 
FROM T1 as A 
INNER JOIN T2 as B
ON B.C = A.C
```

Comment: Thanks for your return, Did you mean Full cache mode ? yes, is good for performence but doesn't meet my need which is to fetch all matched rows. And I need lookup to can redirect unmatched rows to table T3 and this is impossible for the first load when table T2 is empty.

Comment: why do you use `Lookup` when you have the reference table empty?  and where are`Matched` and `Unmatched` rows coming from?

Comment: Rows are coming from table T1, first load the reference table T2 is empty so all unmatched rows will be inserted in reference table T2 and T3. Then, i will add a surrogate key based on columns B and C but I need to get all values of column B with the same value of C. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: `all unmatched rows will be inserted in reference table T2 and T3.` where did you get the `unmatched rows`?

Comment: From Table T1 which is my source table

Comment: Compared to which table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198671/discussion-between-long-and-medec).

Answer (score -1):

If LONG's answer does not address your needs, you'd need to write a Script Transformation, operating in asynchronous mode (1 row of input can yield 0 to many output rows)

If the source data/T1 wouldn't contain duplicate C values, then the pre-execute phase of the component could cache the result of column B & C from T2 into local memory. Then for each source row that flows through, you'd need to loop through the results and append the B values into the data flow.

This gets trickier if T1 can have duplicate-ish data as you'd need to be querying the target table for each row that flows through - but you'd also have to track the B/C values that have already rolled through as you might need to reference those Bs as well.

You can also evaluate a Merge Join as I *think* that allows multiple rows to be emitted but I'm guessing you'll have more control over performance with a script transformation.

Either way, when you pull T2 table in, write a custom query and only select the columns you need (B&C).